# How to pass .load() if image already loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following issue.

I have a Webapplication that shows an image if i click on a icon.

```
$('#ModalArtImage img').load(function(){ 
    $('#ModalArtImage').css('visibility','visible').zIndex(9999);
});
```

this works fine.

To close the just opend DIV (Imagecontainer) I use this

```
$('.imgWindow').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

`.imgWindow` is the total window (Imagecontainer).

If I close the Imagecontainer and press the icon again, the image is already loaded from 
first click and it won't access `.load()` so imagecontainer gets not displayed anymore.

The reason why I use `.load()` is, i don't want to show the imagecontainer before the image that should be displayed is loaded completely. So I try to check it by `.load('img')` what actually works.

Is there a way to solve this?

**EDIT:**

Solved this now like:

```
if( $('#ModalArtImage img').prop('complete') )
{
    $('#ModalArtImage').css('visibility','visible').zIndex(9999);
}
else
{
    $('#ModalArtImage img').load(function(){ 
        $('#ModalArtImage').css('visibility','visible').zIndex(9999);
    });
}
```

thx to **sahbeewah**

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: i would but i can't, this goes throu a big project and a lot of including stuff and custom functions. Actually is simple explained but just because i talk about the main problem :) Img is getting created by php and passed to jquery so sometimes the passed code is equal because imagename was the same. In this case system thinks nothing has changed. I can't rebuild this with pure javascript/jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `complete` property on `img` elements that shows whether an image has finished loading.

```
var showImage = function() {
    $('#ModalArtImage').css('visibility','visible').zIndex(9999);
};

var $img = $('#ModalArtImage img');

if ($img.prop('complete')) {
    showImage();
} else {
    $img.load(showImage);
}
```